# Powershell parallel execution of different commands inside script

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a PS1 file with Invoke-RestMethod on 10 different urls. I want to make them execute in parallel and get the data from them. All the examples I've seen are for running scripts in parallel.

How can I execute:

```
$dataA = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://xyz/A' -WebSession $WebSession -Method Post -Body $queryA
.
.
.
$dataK = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://xyz/K' -WebSession $WebSession -Method Post -Body $queryK
```

The above code in parallel, such that I could use the data in dataA to dataK outside the parallel block.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Powershell Workflow](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powershell-workflows-the-basics/).

```
workflow paralleltest {
    
     parallel {
    
       $dataA = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://xyz/A' -WebSession $WebSession -Method Post -Body $queryA

       $dataK = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://xyz/K' -WebSession $WebSession -Method Post -Body $queryK
    
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the cmdlet "ForEach-Object" with the parameter "-Parallel" explained here: [PowerShell ForEach-Object Parallel Feature](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/)

Although, I havent done it before, I would suggest the following:

1. Define your variables $dataA..$dataZ

2.`$dataA..$dataZ|ForEach-Object...-parallel`

Comment: Tat is for running the same command multiple times right?

Comment: Well...the command "invoke..." is the same but the rest is ofc different.